# Find if $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^3}{x^3+y^6}$ is continuous at the origin

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\cfrac{xy^3}{x^3+y^6}, & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
0, & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$

I did:

$$x = y \\
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{y^4}{y^3+y^6} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{y}{1+y^3} = \\
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} 0/1 = 0$$

$$x = -y \\
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{-y^4}{-y^3+y^6} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{-y}{-1+y^3} = 0/-1 = 0$$

$$0 \le |\frac{xy^3}{x^3+y^6}| \le \frac{|x||y|^3}{|x^3+y^6|} \le \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{|x^3+y^6|} \le ?$$

I'm not sure how to continue. Help?

Comment: I would further add, this function is not even continuous in a neighborhood of the origin. Note if $x = -y^2$, then the denominator is $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$f(y^3,y)=\frac{y^6}{y^9+y^6}=\frac1{y^3+1}$$and that$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac1{y^3+1}=1.$$

Comment: How did you know you had to use $y^3$?

Comment: I did knot *know*. Since the degree of the numerator was not greater thatn the degree of the denominator, I suspected that the function was discontinuous at the origin and then I tried a few paths.

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire sometimes you want to look for a way to reduce a two variable polynomial to a single variable by making a substitution as was done here. This can involve some guess-and-test.

Comment: *Since the degree of the numerator was not greater thatn the degree of the denominator, I suspected that the function was discontinuous* why?

Comment: It's a matter of practice.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate $f(y^2,y)=\frac{y^5}{y^6}=\frac{1}{y}\to \infty$, as $y\to 0$.  This, with other answers, shows the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy^3}{x^3+y^6}$$
For $y^3=x^2$
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^3}{x^3+x^4}=\frac{1}{1+x}$$
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1+x}=1$$
The limit does not exist.